# Why using Sonar Scanner prevents C# compiler from creating Razor Views assembly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, sonarqube

We have a small Asp.Net Core application that has a few cshtml files. Building it runs the C# compiler twice:

1. Once is to produce the assembly for the application itself, e.g. JavascriptClient.dll
2. The other time is to produce the Razor Views assembly, e.g. JavascriptClient.Views.dll

Strange thing happened when we activated the Sonar Scanner - JavascriptClient.Views.dll is no longer produced and no Sonar warnings are output!

I tracked it down to the `/errorlog` command line switch of the C# compiler. The following short annotated transcript captures the problem:

```
C:\\src\JavascriptClient\JavascriptClient> Test-Path .\obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\JavascriptClient.Views.dll
False
```

So the Views assembly does not exist initially.

```
C:\\src\JavascriptClient\JavascriptClient> fc.exe C:\temp\1.txt c:\temp\2.txt
Comparing files C:\TEMP\1.txt and C:\TEMP\2.TXT
***** C:\TEMP\1.txt
/out:obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\JavascriptClient.Views.dll
/errorlog:C:\\src\JavascriptClient\JavascriptClient\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\JavascriptClient.Views.dll.RoslynCA
.json
/target:library
***** C:\TEMP\2.TXT
/out:obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\JavascriptClient.Views.dll
/target:library
*****
```

The two files **c:\temp\1.txt** and **c:\temp\2.txt** are identical except for a single line difference - the former specifies the `/errorlog` switch.

```
C:\\src\JavascriptClient\JavascriptClient> dotnet "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.110\Roslyn\bincore\csc.dll" '@c:\temp\1.txt'
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 2.10.0.0 (45b37117)
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\\src\JavascriptClient\JavascriptClient> Test-Path .\obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\JavascriptClient.Views.dll
False
```

Running the C# compiler with the parameters from **c:\temp\1.txt** succeeds, but the Views assembly is not generated!

```
C:\\src\JavascriptClient\JavascriptClient> dotnet "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.110\Roslyn\bincore\csc.dll" '@c:\temp\2.txt'
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 2.10.0.0 (45b37117)
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\\src\JavascriptClient\JavascriptClient> Test-Path .\obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\JavascriptClient.Views.dll

True
```

Running the same command line without the `/errorlog` switch **does** generate the Views assembly!

Please, find below the abridged version of **c:\temp\1.txt**:

```
/unsafe-
/checked-
/nowarn:NU5105,1701,1702,1701,1702
/nostdlib+
/errorreport:prompt
/warn:4
/define:TRACE;DEBUG;NETCOREAPP;NETCOREAPP2_2
/reference:...
...
/reference:...
/debug+
/debug:full
/filealign:512
/optimize-
/out:obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\JavascriptClient.Views.dll
/errorlog:C:\src\JavascriptClient\JavascriptClient\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\JavascriptClient.Views.dll.RoslynCA.json
/target:library
/warnaserror+
/utf8output
/deterministic+
/analyzer:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.analyzers\2.2.0\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Analyzers.dll"
/analyzer:C:\Users\me\.nuget\packages\microsoft.codeanalysis.analyzers\1.1.0\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers.dll
/analyzer:C:\Users\me\.nuget\packages\microsoft.codeanalysis.analyzers\1.1.0\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Analyzers.dll
/analyzer:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.analyzers\2.2.0\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Analyzers.dll"
obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\Razor\Pages\Error.g.cshtml.cs obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\Razor\Pages\Index.g.cshtml.cs ...
/warnaserror+:NU1605
```

Notice, I have removed all the Sonar analyzers from the parameters!

The documentation for the `/errorlog` parameter is here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/listed-alphabetically There is nothing there really.

So, here I am lost. How do I resolve this conundrum? I mean I want both Sonar and Views assembly.

Comment: Why is this SonarQube related? You proofed yourself it is related to the /errorlog option. Maybe [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-3.1) documentation page can help you.

Comment: SonarQube is what started it. The only reason I have this flag is because of SonarQube. I mention it because it is one of the triggers. I do not believe many people pass this flag to the compiler, but many use Sonar Scanner and could thus know about this and help.

Comment: I do not see how this link helps. If you do - please elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was [a bug](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/34101) in the csc compiler that prevented the output assembly being produced in some circumstances when the `/errorlog` switch is passed to MSBuild. This can show up when using the SonarScanner for MSBuild as it sets this build property. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57149708/sonarscanner-c-not-honoring-in-code-stylecop-warning-suppression) for more information.

Try upgrading to a newer version of the build tools (v16.1 or later).

Comment: We are using `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.110\Roslyn\bincore\csc.dll`. Do you mean we should use .net core higher than `2.2.110` ? Can you advise which version to use?

Comment: Yes, build using a newer version (your app can still target an earlier framework version). It looks like the .NET SDK 3.0.100 ships with MSBuild v16.3 so that would do.

Comment: I need to check this, but I will accept your answer for now. Hopefully it indeed solves it.